# Proof for $a < b$ given $a^2<b^2$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I'm currently going through Spivak's calculus and have come across this problem:

> If $a,b \ge 0$ and $a^2<b^2$ then $a<b$

You're supposed to use another property proven earlier:
$0\le a<b$, then $a^2<b^2$

But i don't understand how to express this mathematically. I can understand that if both a and b are greater than zero and the final outcome is correct, this statement must apply, but how do you prove that?
The problem i'm facing is that $a^2<b^2$ does not imply that the condition is also correct.

Comment: Also, can anybody tell me how to get the less than or equal to / greater than or equal to sign?

Comment: \le and \ge. See the [mathjax formatting guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/).

Comment: less than or equal to : \le, greater than or equal to : \ge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a contapositive proof.

If $a = b \implies a^2 = b^2$ (and it is not true that $a^2 < b^2$.  So if $a^2 < b^2 \implies a \ne b$).

If $a > b \implies a^2 > b^2$ (and it is not true that $a^2 < b^2$. So if $a^2 < b^2 \implies a \le b$).

So if $a \not < b \implies a^2 \not < b^2$.  So, contrapositively, $a^2 < b^2 \implies a < b$ (because if $a^2 < b^2$ then it is absolutely impossible for $a < b$ not to be true.)

Answer (score 3):

I think the other side does not have to be used. It is simply because

$$b - a = \frac{b^2-a^2}{b+a}.$$

Comment: Well yes, that proof is correct, but i'm curious as to how we can use the statement that was proven earlier to prove this.

Comment: I don't think the other side can prove this side, although both sides of implications are true, as in most of the logical equivalences as far as I know.

Answer (score 2):

$a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$
so $a-b$ and $a^2-b^2$ have the same sign

Answer (score 1):

You will not/cannot be able to use the fact that you have stated (wherever you used it, you would be assuming the very thing that you are trying to prove, and concluding that which you already know!).

I believe a direct proof is best in this scenario:

Since $a^2<b^2$, we get that $b^2-a^2>0$, or $(b-a)(b+a)>0$. Now since $a,b\ge 0$, we know that $b+a>0$, which means that $b-a>0$ (because $(b+a)$ and $(b-a)$ must have the same sign in order for their product to be positive). But $b-a>0$ immediately implies that $b>a$ or $a<b$.